# G++ command line works with threading flag, linux makefile does not

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, makefile

This command line works beautifully on ubuntu (using C++ and threading):

```
g++ -std=c++11 prog.cpp -o prog.out -lpthread
```

my makefile just blows up:

```
all: main

main: prog.o
    g++ -o prog prog.o

prog.o: prog.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c prog.cpp -lpthread
```

I'm not sure but it appears the `-lpthread` flag isn't being picked up. It's late and I've been working on the makefile for two hours, and any help would be appreciated.

make returns an error:undefined reference to 'pthread_create'

Comment: Move `-lpthread` into the recipe for `main`.

Comment: Do not edit your question to include the answer. It invalidates having asked the question in the first place.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. I realized I had left it out and hand edited it back in.

Answer (score 3):

You neglected to explain what "blows up" means.

But presumably it means "fails to link" and that would be because you put it on the wrong command.

`-l` is a *linker* flag but you have it in the *compilation* command.

You need to move it to the `main` target.

Also you make note of [make rule #2](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/#rule2) (from the GNU make maintainer):

> Every non-.PHONY rule must update a file with the exact name of its target.
>
> Make sure every command script touches the file “$@“–not “../$@“, or “$(notdir $@)“, but exactly $@. That way you and GNU make always agree.

You could also *greatly* simplify your makefile (down to essentially nothing) if you wanted to take advantage of the [built-in rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).

```
CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
LDLIBS := -lpthread

all: prog
```

That's it.

Comment: Nice. You know your makefile's.